# In latex, How to fix built in caption in algorithm package?

Tags: captions, algorithms, algorithmicx

I am using my university template. I used the algorithm package to write my thesis. However, instead of "Algorithm 1" it writes "Loa 1" in the caption. How can I fix it?
here is my code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{An algorithm with caption}\label{alg:cap}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Require $n \geq 0$
\Ensure $y = x^n$
\State $y \gets 1$
\State $X \gets x$
\State $N \gets n$
\While{$N \neq 0$}
\If{$N$ is even}
    \State $X \gets X \times X$
    \State $N \gets \frac{N}{2}$  \Comment{This is a comment}
\ElsIf{$N$ is odd}
    \State $y \gets y \times X$
    \State $N \gets N - 1$
\EndIf
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please extend your code fragment to complete small document. You have in document preamble some definition(s) used in `algorithmic` code.

Comment: I changed it. Can you help me?

Comment: J cant reproduce your result. It is quite different what you show in question (lines are numbered, caption has form: `Algorithm 1 An algorithm with caption`. Differences can arise that you have installed older version of packages and LaTeX or the image is not produced by showed code.

Comment: I am using Livetex 2022.

Comment: It says Loa4, this how can I solve this to say algorithm?

Comment: I can't find the algorithm package.  Algorithms, algorithmcx and algorithm2e fine.  Anyway, somewhere there is a macro \algorithmname or \algoname or some variant which should contain either "Algorithm" or "Loa4".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because provide MWE works as expected and by it is not possible to reproduce OP problem.

Answer (score 0):

To long for comment ...

- with use of packages

```
article.cls     2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
algorithm.sty   2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithm' - floating environm
ent
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
  ifthen.sty    2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
algpseudocode.sty    
algorithmicx.sty    2005/04/27 v1.2 Algorithmicx
  lipsum.sty    2021-09-20 v2.7 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
l3keys2e.sty    2022-06-22 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
   expl3.sty    2022-11-02 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-pdftex.def    2022-10-26 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
  lipsum.ltd
```

in your MWE (Minimal Working Example), where I add option for numbering code lines:

```
%\listfiles                   % to check, which version of packages are used
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{algorithm}[t]
    \caption{An algorithm with caption}
    \label{alg:cap}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require $n \geq 0$
\Ensure $y = x^n$
\State $y \gets 1$
\State $X \gets x$
\State $N \gets n$
\While{$N \neq 0$}
\If{$N$ is even}
    \State $X \gets X \times X$
    \State $N \gets \frac{N}{2}$  \Comment{This is a comment}
\ElsIf{$N$ is odd}
    \State $y \gets y \times X$
    \State $N \gets N - 1$
\EndIf
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I got

[image]

- As you can see, your code example works as expected (and as shown on [Overleaf instruction: The algpseudocode and algorithm packages](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Algorithms)).
- As I said in comment, if you compile provided MWE, than you should got the same result.
- Showed image of compilation result was not produced by showed MWE and therefore cause of your problem is not accessible. I can't help you.

Comment: can you help me if I upload the logfile? what do I need to provide?

Comment: @homataha, please first test my MWE as it is (as new file in your system) and inform me, what result you will get. If not the same, than your LaTeX installation need to be updated.

Comment: I get the same result as yours. My system is correct.

Comment: @homataha  Than you solve your problem? If not yet, than to my MWE ad in step by step packages and definitions from your document preamble and see which one change result of compilation.